# Split a string into individual characters and place the characters into a table

Tags: string, lua, lua-table

I'm trying to make a program that can take a word as an input, find each letter of the word and then run it through an encoding system I have. Each letter is assigned to a specific number. I'd like the program to be able to identify a letter and save it's number into a variable so it can be run through a few math operations. I have the math portion done and working, but it can only take one character at a time. Judging from some tutorials I've found online for the LUA tables and strings library, the code I have should work, but the table always prints 'nil'.

```
print("Word?")
str = io.read()
chars = {}

for i in string.gmatch(str, "%U") do
    table.insert(t, i)
end

print(chars)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code mostly working as you expect it, but you mistyped the table name in `table.insert`; it should be using `chars` instead of `t`:

```
table.insert(chars, i)
```