# How to have a function execute on a range of values in a Lua table

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a program that takes letters as input, finds their assigned number in a table, and runs some math operations on that number before giving the finished pair of numbers (the encoded letter) as an output. I have functions set up to check which character is inputted, and to run the math, but my code looks like this:

```
checkchar(chars[1])
checkchar(chars[2])
checkchar(chars[3])
checkchar(chars[4])
checkchar(chars[5])
checkchar(chars[6])
checkchar(chars[7])
checkchar(chars[8])
checkchar(chars[9])
checkchar(chars[10])
checkchar(chars[11])
checkchar(chars[12])
checkchar(chars[13])
checkchar(chars[14])
checkchar(chars[15])
checkchar(chars[16])
checkchar(chars[17])
checkchar(chars[18])
checkchar(chars[19])
checkchar(chars[20])
checkchar(chars[21])
checkchar(chars[22])
checkchar(chars[23])
checkchar(chars[24])
checkchar(chars[25])
```

Hardly efficient, plus it imposes a 25 character limit because I really don't want to paste this thing 100 times.

Is there a way that I can have the program find the number of characters that have been inputted and use that number to decide how many values to run with the function, and then use that number again to print out just what was inputted so I don't have to print a bunch of black spaces?

Comment: How did you get your input? Show that part of code.

Comment: Why are you not just operating over the values in the table that you got based on the answer to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167239/split-a-string-into-individual-characters-and-place-the-characters-into-a-table)? Using `ipairs` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure if I understand your problem correctly, but would iterating using a for loop be solution of the problem? Like

```
for i=1,25 do
  checkchar(chars[i])
end
```

Even better

```
for _, char in pairs(chars) do
  checkchar(char)
end
```

If want to do it event nicer, and store results, you can use map function

```
local result = map(checkchar, chars)
```

Where map is the following

```
function map(func, array)
  local new_array = {}
  for i,v in ipairs(array) do
    new_array[i] = func(v)
  end
  return new_array
end
```